# How long should you wait after 3rd Parvo vaccine?

Tags: dogs, vaccination

I talked to the vet while my puppy was being vaccinated for his 3rd round at 16 weeks. She told me to wait 1-2 weeks before allowing my puppy to walk around outside. Various internet searches turn up a great deal of ranges anywhere from 5-7 days to 3 weeks.

I searched around on scholar and couldn't find anything that gives a risk curve or clear guidance on the right range of days. The difference from 1 to 2 weeks for a 25 lb puppy is a long time.

Does anyone have more concrete (science backed) guidance? I was just going to split the time difference in half aka a week and a half since that's within the vet's range.

Comment: It seems the veterinarian gave you explicit instructions, why would you dispute them?

Comment: @GCCambell the vet gave me instructions to wait between 1-2 weeks, I'm not disputing that? I'm trying to find studies on that information and trying to understand more about the range that the vet gave me.